# In MySQL, is it faster to delete and then insert or is it faster to update existing rows?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, yii

First of all, let me just say that I'm using the PHP framework Yii, so I'd like to stay within its defined set of SQL statement if possible. I know I could probably create one huge long SQL statement that would do everything, but I'd rather not go there.

OK, imagine I have a table Users and a table FavColors. Then I have a form where users can select their color preferences by checking one or more checkboxes from a large list of possible colors.

Those results are stored as multiple rows in the FavColors table like this (id, user_id, color_id).

Now imagine the user goes in and changes their color preference. In this scenario, what would be the most efficient way to get the new color preferences into the database?

**Option 1:**

- Do a mass delete of all rows where user_id matches
- Then do a mass insert of all new rows

**Option 2:**

- Go through each current row to see what's changed, and update accordingly
- If more rows need to be inserted, do that.
- If rows need to be deleted, do that.

I like option one because it only requires two statements, but something just feels wrong about deleting a row just to potentially put back almost the exact same data in. There's also the issue of making the ids auto-increment to higher values more quickly, and I don't know if that should be avoided whenever possible.

Option 2 will require a lot more programming work, but would prevent situations where I'd delete a row just to create it again. However, adding more load in PHP may not be worth the decrease in load for MySQL.

Any thoughts? What would you all do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`UPDATE` is by far much faster. When you `UPDATE`, the table records are just being rewritten with new data. And all this must be done again on `INSERT`.

When you `DELETE`, the indexes should be updated (remember, you delete the whole row, not only the columns you need to modify) and data blocks may be moved (if you hit the `PCTFREE` limit). Also deleting and adding new changes records IDs on auto_increment, so if those records have relationships that would be broken, or would need updates too. I'd go for `UPDATE`.

That's why you should prefer `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead of `REPLACE`.

The former one is an `UPDATE` operation in case of a key violation, while the latter one is `DELETE / INSERT`

**UPDATE:** Here's an example `INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;`

For more details read update [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Unfortunately, when you're using a framework based on ActiveRecord, it's not always easy to create a custom SQL statement and include "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE". If I do that, I'll have to manually create a query, and that query most likely won't translate if I need to switch DBMS in the future.

Comment: check out if your framework provides any kind of feature which will help you to pull this off. Otherwise, just do an `update`.

Comment: Would updating 10 rows individually with 10 SQL statements really be faster than deleting 10 and then adding 10 with two SQL statements?

Comment: try to do all your updates in 1 single SQL statement. That helps.

Comment: I can't do it all in 1 single SQL statement because the values I'm updating them to are not consistent across all updated rows. Given that, is it STILL better to update 10 rows 1 by 1 than to do a mass delete and then insert?

Comment: well from where I am sitting I would say go for `UPDATE` instead of `DELETE & UPDATE`. Best way to know is to benchmark your code. Just `time` both operations & see which one takes longer.

Comment: @movieyoda, I would certainly give you credit, but I can't upvote yet since I don't have enough points. I also want to hear what others have to say before pick a correct answer, but it will most likely be yours :)

Answer (score 1):

Philip, 
Have you tried doing prepared statements? With prepared statements you can batch one query with different parameters and call it multiple times. At the end of your loop, you can execute all of them with minimal amount of network latency. I have used prepared statements with php and it works great. Little more confusing than java prepared statements.